# file_get_contents giving warning

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

```
    $url="http://www.smszone.in/sendsms.asp?page=".$page."&username=".$usrnm."&password=".$passw."&number=".$mobile."&message="."Hi ".$admi.' '.implode($msg)."  Is issued ..."."\n"."Regards";
    $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
    if($homepage)
    {
      echo "Message Send Compleated...";
    }
    else{
      echo "Something Went Wrong...";
```

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.smszone.in/sendsms.asp?page=SendSmsBulk&username=*******&password=****&number=**********&message=Hi Izza AMGR-8A:3/1-BCS-GR:2/1-CCL Is issued ... Regards): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in F:\xampp\htdocs\loglib\logissue.php on line 40
>   Something Went Wrong...

This is the error i am getting when i run this through my php code. If i copy the generated url and paste in any browser, it works....

Note: I am using xampp

Comment: Have you tried `file_get_contents(urlencode($url));`?

Comment: ...or at least url encode all the values (specifically the message). A browser does the url encoding for you automatically, PHP don't, so you need to do it manually.

Comment: `&message='.urlencode($message)`

Comment: 'file_get_contents(urlencode($url));' not working

Comment: Don't encode the whole thing. Encode the variable values.

Comment: Yes, that was a bad idea, didn't think enough. Try encoding the values and especially the message, which contains spaces (as suggested by @MagnusEriksson).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [http_build_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function to build correct query string:

```
$query = [
  'page' => $page,
  'username' => $user,
  // ... 
];

$url = 'http://...?'.http_build_query($query);
```